# Compute expected value of the event

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $S = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 \}$ be a sample space with $P(x) = k^{2}x$ where $x$ is a member of $S$,
and $k$ is a positive constant. Compute $\mathbb{E}(S)$. Round your answer to the nearest hundredths.

I have tried solving this problem by substituting the set values and using probability formulas, but everything has been incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please add to your post your thoughts while trying to solve this problem. By the way, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make things look nicer.

Comment: Have you been able to find $k$?

Comment: Henry- I have not been able to find k, I am unsure how to.

Comment: Ertxiem- Thank you! I will try and revise the post.

Comment: Hint: if you sum all probabilities you should get...

Comment: @Ertxiem What would I do to find one of the probabilities using the information given? Say I wanted to find the probability of the element 4 in the set. Would I use the probability formula given and just plug for in for x, or is there something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been given a really poorly stated question.

First of all, $S$ is defined as a set and then you are asked for $\textbf{E}(S)$, which does not make sense. Instead, I would interpret the question as:

> Let $X$ be a random element selected from the set $S$, with $P(X=x)=P(x)=k^2x$, where $k$ is a positive constant. Find $\textbf{E}(X)$.

Now as Henry states, you need to solve for the value of $k$. The fact that you will need to use here is **the sum of all the $P(x)$'s must be 1.**

Next, you can simply apply the definition of expected value: $\textbf{E}(X)=\sum_{x} x P(x)$, where the sum is over all valid values of $x$ (i.e., all $x \in S$).

Comment: You have a typo: it should be $P(x)=k^2x$.

Comment: @Ertxiem Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @kccu I am sorry, but I am completely lost. Could you explain how to find k, and how that would be used in finding the final answer?

Comment: @Rian The total probabilities of all the elements of $S$ must sum to $1$ (this is a rule of probability - the probability of the entire sample space is $1$). That is, $P(1)+P(2)+\cdots+P(8)=1$. This (once you substitute in the definition of $P(x)$) is an equation involving $k$, so there is a positive value of $k$ that makes it true. Write down that equation and find that value of $k$.

Comment: @kccu Ah alright, thank you I think I got it!